# USB Audio interface 50Hz + harmonics noise when either laptop or speakers are plugged in

Tags: audio, noise, mains

As soon as I plug in either my laptop or my speakers to the wall, I get an unbearable amount of noise in my guitar recording.

Signal chain: Guitar --(1/4 jack)-> Audio Interface --(USB)-> PC --(Power brick)-> Wall socket

In the above setup, the PC is the only thing that's plugged into the wall. That should mean there is no ground loop issue right?

There is nothing else plugged in to this socket.

If I unplug my laptop from the wall, but plug in the speakers which are connected to the audio interface with a 3.5mm->RCA cable, I also get noise.

Touching the guitar strings only slightly lowers the noise but not enough.

I tried various setups with varying results:

- both laptop and speakers plugged in = -43 db
- unplug just speakers = -43 db
- unplug just laptop = -45 db
- unplug just laptop but disconnect the speaker from the audio interface = -56 db
- unplug both = -63 db

The noise is not only 50Hz but also every harmonic of it. See below image

[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Y-capacitor leakage. Do you have access to ground somewhere?

Comment: What does it mean? I'm not an electrical engineer

Comment: @Elite_Dragon1337 You've done nothing here to really show us a clear diagram. Text and arrows won't cut it. Use a methodological approach to track down the source of the problem. In particular, read and follow [this guide](https://content-files.shure.com/KnowledgeBaseFiles/ground-loop-bill-whitlock.pdf). Especially, where it starts to introduce dummy connectors with resistors in them on page 13. Some of what I see there looks like power supply hash to me. So there are more steps required to verify that. But read, learn, do. You'll figure it out if you take a stepwise methodological approach.

Comment: Neither my laptop charger nor my speakers even have a 3rd prong, so can it even be a ground issue?

Comment: A variation of it called Y-capacitor leakage. Do you have access to a grounded outlet, a water faucet or heating element (water)?

Comment: I'm guessing you're right. My laptop charger is of the European Type-F kind but I'm abroad right now and directly plugging it into a Type-A socket which doesn't have a ground. So I guess it's the leakage current thing you're talking about, leaking to my USB audio interface. (Again I'm no electrical engineer). I've placed an order for a proper converter with the ground connection (Type I). Will report back once it arrives

Comment: You said your laptop charger doesn't have a ground connector, but google says the Type-F connector includes ground.  Does that mean you took a grounded connector and removed the ground (perhaps without realizing it)? If so, you should mention that in your question.

Comment: @user1850479 It is already mentioned that a Type-F plug is plugged into Type-A socket. I assume a travel adapter.

Comment: @Justme He also said he has no ground plug on the power supply, so if true the Type-A via adapter would be ok. It's not clear to me what he actually did.

Comment: @user1850479 Type-F is a grounded plug.

Comment: I'm EE by day and do stage audio by night. Most pro-audio USB interfaces have very good supply rejection on the signal side but very few offer you to break up ground from USB shell to XLR shield. What you should do it to introduce proper ground in the system. A grounded plug _may_ solve it for you, but it's up to some designer at the manufacturer as your laptop is seen as a low voltage secondary side on a Class II product, so earth leakage affecting pro audio is not a concern for them. The obvious exception here is IBM/Lenovo which are dead silent straight from the 3.5 mm jack.

Comment: Can confirm grounded plug has solved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a charger which has a grounded plug.

But you are connecting it to wall socket that doesn't provide ground.

It needs to be connected to a wall socket that provides a ground.

Most likely it reads on the charger itself, so you are using it incorrectly.

And that is why you have 50 Hz ground loops.

The electrical engineering explanation is that the power brick has filter capacitors from Live and Neutral to Earth/Ground. When the ground is missing, the caps are actually making things worse. If you had a desktop PC with metal case, the metal case that should be grounded via mains plug will now be weakly connected to half mains AC voltage, like 115 VAC in a 230 VAC country.

That is enough to damage things when hot-plugged together and can feel like vibration and tingling when you touch metal parts of the PC.

Comment: Can confirm grounded plug has solved the issue